# ¿como remplazar un archivo cuando dejen de usar?C#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que muestra unos pdfs y tiene dos accesos uno el usuario que los visualiza y otro el administrador que actualiza los pdf el problema es que al actualizar los archivos dara error si otra persona los esta viendo.

codigo de remplazar.

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog { DefaultExt = ".pdf", Filter = "PDF documents (.pdf)|*.pdf" };
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName))
        {
            try
            {
                string destino = red + listPdf[CurrentPdf];
                if (File.Exists(destino))
                {
                    File.Delete(destino);
                    File.Copy(dlg.FileName, destino);
                }
                else File.Copy(dlg.FileName, destino);
                pdfViewer.LoadFile(destino);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show("Error \n" + ex.Message);}
        }
```

codigo de cargar

```
pdfViewer.LoadFile(red + listPdf[CurrentPdf = 0]);
```

Comment: Pero esto es un problema de diseño, como esperas que te ayudemos? porque el codigo hace lo correcto.

Comment: Siempre tendrás problemas al compartir recursos, yo te recomiendo que del lado del cliente le muestres una copia del pdf y tengas un "estado(bool)" para los pdfs, de esta forma tu app del cliente sepa cuando haya una nueva actualización, así podrías notificarlo y pedirle que acepte la actualización, reinicias todo Application.Restart(); y vuelves a mostrar el pdf.

Comment: no hay una forma de guardar el archivo en una objeto como en python para que no dependa de el archivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que el problema viene porque el usuario bloquea el archivo en red (Supongo que es un archivo remoto por tu código)

Yo te planteo la siguiente solución: Conecta la carpeta en concreto como unidad de red de tu equipo y fuerza por consola el borrado del archivo.

```
strCmdText= "del /f <ruta/del/archivo.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Espero que esta solución te funcione o al menos encuentres otro camino por el que solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿No sería el mismo problema?, porque tratas de eliminar un recurso usado por otro proceso.

Comment: por el momento funciona

Comment: Es lo mismo, pero al usar el modificador `/f` fuerzas el borrado